# including javascript via theme.info doesn't work.

Tags: theming, .info

I'm trying to include a simple javascript into my theme using the theme.info

It works like a charm on my home-setup but when I try to load in on a real page it doesn't include the .js-files (not even an empty `<script>`-Tag is displayed in the source).

The Code:

```
...
engine = phptemplate
stylesheets[all][] = css/bjqs.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css
scripts[] = js/bjqs-1.3.js 
scripts[] = 'js/jquery-latest.min.js'
features[] = main_menu
regions[slider] = Slider
...
```

The CSS-Files get included on both projects without any problem.

Comment: The Js file you try to incude is bjqs-1.3.js ? Drupal is already bundled with jQuery, could you tell me why you include jQuery using the theme.info?

Comment: Also, if you're looking to change the version of jQuery being used by Drupal, take a look at the [jquery_update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have aggregation on in configuration > development > performance?

If so, this causes the problem. Clear all caches, and the problem should be solved.